# What is @KafkaKey annotation used for

Tags: apache-kafka, micronaut

I am new in Kafka and micronaut and I do not understand the usage of @KafkaKey. What I found on internet is :

> The Kafka key can be specified by providing a parameter annotated with
>   @KafkaKey. If no such parameter is specified the record is sent with a null key.

So what exactly it means? How it will effect me if I do not use it ?

Answer (score 1):

Most important effect of Kafka message keys is partitioning. For example if the key chosen was a user id then all data for a given user would be sent to the same partition. If you wouldn't specify the key of messages Kafka would use round-robin strategy for message distribution.

Comment: It _affects_ performance. :) Cause with wrong usage of KafkaKey, for example, setting one key for all messages you can send all your data to one partition what usually decrease performance.

Comment: @wardziniak If I not set a key messages would be distributed, as I mentioned in answer. If I set constant key for all messages they would not.

Comment: So if we are sending a message to kafka after receiving a request by our controller, do we need to get this key from the requestParam?

Comment: @user1474111 If you don't have any specific partitioning policy in your system and strategy "messages are distributed between partitions randomly" is okay for you just don't specify a key.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka preserves the order within the partitions. As you specify a key for a particular message type, the message type is bound to a particular partition associated with that key. Since the order of messages is preserved in a partition, you can preserve the message order by specifying a key. This is particularly useful if you are working with state machines.